# scrollview fillviewport linearlayout

Tags: android, scrollview, android-linearlayout

Is there any way to have a ScrollView with **android:fillViewport="true"** and a child LinearLayout filling all the view when the content of the LinearLayout  is not hight enough?

So far, in a LinearLayout inside a ScrollView we have to use **android:layout_height="wrap_content"**. Can we add something else for filling all ScrollView?

Comment: use match_parent in layout height

Answer (score 2):

What's the point? LinearLayout content won't stretch to fill ScrollView anyway. If you want to center LinearLayout in (fillViewPorted) ScrollView, use `android:gravity="center"` in LinearLayout. If you want to use LinearLayout weights to fill screen, don't use ScrollView, as it's height is potentially infinite. If

Answer (score 1):

Set the android:layout_weight of the contents to 1.0. That will force the contents to use the available empty space when it is shorter than the ScrollView. It only works when android:fillViewport=
"true" is set on the scroll view.

Source: http://www.curious-creature.com/2010/08/15/scrollviews-handy-trick/